# What does this line of code do ` ++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)];`

Tags: java

I would like to know that as I am learning Java from tutorials and there is a program for rolling the dice 1000 times and printing its frequency.

```java
import java.util.Random;
public class RollDicewitharray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r=new Random();
        int arr[]= new int[7];

        System.out.println("diceNo.\tFrequency");
        for (int roll = 1; roll < 1000; roll++) {

            ++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)];                  /* this line */

        }
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+"\t"+arr[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: try adding some breakpoints and instead of 'run code' use 'debug code'. In Debug view in Your IDE You'll see everything step by step. Other approach try to talk to Yourself what is happening line by line, out loud ;)
Write latter if that helped, if not we'll try something else ;)

Comment: @umant Narayan You can accept 1 of the solutions below which you thinks it helped you most by clicking the hollow looking tick beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.nextInt(6)` produces a random integer between 0 and 5. Adding 1 to it gives you a random dice roll between 1 and 6.

The `arr` array is used to count the number of times each dice roll occurred, so `++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)]` increments the count for the current roll.

When the first loop is done, `arr[1]` holds the number of 1s, `arr[2]` the number of 2s, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To summarise all, this program simulates rolling a six-sided dice 1000 times and records the ***occurrences*** of each number rolled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r=new Random();
    int arr[]= new int[7];                    //Craete an array with 7 int elements
    System.out.println("diceNo.\tFrequency");

    for(int roll=1;roll<1000;roll++){         //Loop 1000 times
        ++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)];                //Randomly pick arr[1] to 
    }                                         //arr[6] and plus one to it        

    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+arr[i]);    //Print occurrence of 1-6
    }    
}
```

**Breaking the following code:**

```
++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)];     //r.nextInt(6) will be evaluated first:
```

---

`r.nextInt(6)` returns random value of `(0-5)`, so you have:

```
++arr[1+(random 0 to 5)];  //+1 will be evaluated next:
```

So you are generating a random value of `1-6`. Next you add 1 to the array:

```
++arr[random 1 to 6];      //+1 to arr[1] or arr[2] or arr[3] or arr[4] or arr[5] or arr[6]
```

It can now be interpreted as:

```
arr[1] +=1;  //or
arr[2] +=1;  //or
arr[3] +=1;  //or
arr[4] +=1;  //or
arr[5] +=1;  //or
arr[6] +=1;
```

---

So after running your program, if your array looks like:

```
 [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]   Array index
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 |175|170|165|170|165|175| <-- arr 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

It means 1 was rolled 175 times, 
2 was rolled 170 times, 
3 was rolled 165 times,
and so on..
```

Answer (score 1):

`1 + r.nextInt(6)` draws a random number from 1 to 6 inclusive.

`++arr[1 + r.nextInt(6)];` increments that element of the array `arr`.

So a frequency distribution of dice-rolls is built up. The zeroth element of the array is not used. Which is why it's set up with 7 elements. Wasteful perhaps? You tell me.

Answer (score 0):

1. r.nextInt(6) - get the random number < 6;
2. arr[1+r.nextInt(6)] - get an item from the array arr with index 1 + random number from step 1;
3. ++arr[1+r.nextInt(6)] increase the item from step 2 by 1

Answer (score 0):

This line is equivalant to:

```
int number = r.nextInt(6); // Generates a random number between 0 and 6(exclusive)
int index = number + 1; // Since the faces of dice has value from 1 to 6
int value = arr[index];
and increases this number by 1;
```